Intuition for component form of sum of tensor products
Suppose we have vector spaces $A$ and $B$, and we take two elements $x_1 \otimes y_1$ and $x_2 \otimes y_2$, where $x_1,x_2 \in A $ and $ y_1,y_2 \in B$, from the tensor product space $A \otimes B$. Then we add them together:
$$
z \equiv x_1 \otimes y_1 \; + \; x_2 \otimes y_2
$$
I'm aware that, generally, there is no simplification to the above expression. In particular, the "$+$" symbol above is a formal sum meant to label the element you get from adding the two elements; it does not represent a binary operation that you can compute to get a new simple tensor $x_3 \otimes y_3$.
My question is this: what is the intuition behind the component form of the above  promoting the formal sum into an explicit sum? i.e. if I label the components of the resulting column vector by two indices, one for each component vector space, then:
$$
z_{i;j}=(x_1)_i \; (y_1)_j \; + \; (x_2)_i \; (y_2)_j
$$
Where the "$+$" is now regular algebraic addition. Where in the definition of the tensor product does this nice property come from? The fact that the above property holds for the tensor product of matrices as well is of especial interest to me.

Basis of $A$ (resp. $B$) is ${a_i}{i=1}^n$ (resp. ${b_j}{j=1}^m$. For $x_1,x_2 \in A$, $x_1=(x_1)^i a_i$, $x_2=(x_2)^i a_i$; for $y_1,y_2 \in B$, $y_1=(y_1)^j b_j$, $y_2=(y_2)^j a_j$. Hence $x_1 \otimes y_1=(x_1)^i (y_1)^j a_i \otimes b_j$; similarly $x_2 \otimes y_2=(x_2)^i (y_2)^j a_i \otimes b_j$. $z \in A\otimes B$, $z=z^{ij} a_i \otimes b_j$ and so $z^{ij}=(x_1)^i (y_1)^j +(x_2)^i (y_2)^j $.

So the "nice" property of tensor products I was asking about that gives us this is just that $c(x \otimes y) = (cx \otimes y) = (x \otimes cy)$?

The tensor product is a bilinear map $\otimes: A \times B \to A \otimes B$.

Just so I make sure I understand: this mapping is injective but obviously not surjective right?

${\rm im}\otimes = A \otimes B$ so it is surjective. This is part of the so called universal property of the tensor product.

I thought that surjectivity was determined by the codomain. it will be trivially surjective if you restrict the codomain to the image of $\otimes$, but $A \otimes B$ has non-simple tensors in it. Which elements of $A \times B$ could possibly be mapped to them?

$A \otimes B$ contains elementary tensors like $a \otimes b$; in fact the basis of $A \otimes B$ is a set of elementary tensors.

I'm saying that it contains more than elementary tensors. Maybe I'm just confused by your notation. Are you calling $A \otimes B$ the vector space of simple tensors, or the space generated by them as a basis? if the latter, it couldn't possibly be surjective.

Good point. $A \otimes B$ is the tensor product of vector spaces $A,B$. This vector space contains both elementary (tensors that can be written as $a \otimes b$) and non-elementary (tensors that can only be written as $\sum_i a_i \otimes b_i$) tensors .

I'm not sure this exactly answers you question, but the way I think about tensors of finite dimensional vector spaces is as matrices. If you have vector spaces $A,B$ over some field $K$, with $\dim A=a,\ \dim B=b $, these are isomorphic to $K^a,\ K^b$ respectively. I think of $A\otimes B$ as the vector space of $a\times b$ matrices, with each simple tensor $x_i\otimes y_j$ representing the $(i,k)$ component of a the matrix. Or if you would like to allude to the formal sum notation, a matrix with all zeros except in the $x_i\otimes y_j$ place.
Take some element $\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i x_i\oplus \beta_j y_j$  of $A\otimes B$ where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the standard basis vectors of $A$ and $B$ resp. We can write this element as
$$\sum_{i, j}\alpha_i x_i\otimes \beta_j y_j=\sum_{i, j}\alpha_i \beta_j(x_i\otimes y_j)$$
to view the element as a matrix, we take $\alpha_i\beta_j$ as the $(i,j)$th component, and to recover our matrix. This becomes very intuitive in einstein summation notation with vectors and vectors.
The sum alludes to the fact that if you take vector $\alpha=(\alpha_i)_i$ and column vector $\beta=(\beta_j)_j$, and $T$ be the matrix who's (i,j)th place is given by $x_i\otimes y_j$, the product
$$\alpha T \beta = \sum_{i,j}\alpha_i x_i\otimes \beta_j y_j$$
however we can also write this product component
(even though it will bee a single sum or $1\times 1$ matrix) as
$$(\alpha T \beta)^1_1=\sum_i \alpha^1_i (T \beta)^i_1=\sum_i \alpha^1_i \sum_l T^i_j \beta_1^j=\sum_i \alpha^j_i \sum_j (x_i\otimes y_j) \beta_1^j=\sum_i \alpha^1_i \sum_j (x_i\otimes y_j) \beta_1^j$$
dropping the annoying ones and simplifying a little more, we see
$$\alpha T \beta=(\alpha T \beta)^1_1=\sum_i \alpha_i \sum_j (x_i\otimes y_j) \beta^j=\sum_{i,j} (\alpha_ix_i\otimes \beta^jy_j) $$
and thus we recover our original formal sum :) I hope this helps.

what does the $\oplus$ mean in this context?

@KandC i’m sorry that’s a typo! i was quite tired when i wrote this it’s should be $\otimes$ i’ll fix it when im at my laptop
